# I drove my 2003 Mazda 6 with the handbrake on for about 2.5 km

Tags: mazda, repair, smoke, handbrake, mazda-6

I noticed smoke from the rear tyres with a burning smell. I also put the car in drive with the handbrake engaged to test if they were still working and it moved forward, although, this was on a slight hill.
I suppose they are pretty destroyed right?
Pretty bummed out about it haha, what do you think is wrong with it and how much do you reckon I'm in for?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The hand brake on the Mazda 6 GG seems to act directly on the normal rear brake calipers. Sounds like the heat may have glassed your brake pads. If you don't notice any wobble while braking normally from higher speed, you would only need to replace the brake pads. Should be something like 30$ for a set of pads and maybe half an hour of work.

Comment: Probably also need to see if the brake rotors are warped from the heat.  Not sure if the brake calipers could get warped too.  2.5 KM is a long way to drive a vehicle with the brakes engaged.  Need to determine what was actually smoking.  Whatever it was likely needs replacement.